# Вызов существующей функции через кнопку, missing 1 required positional argument. Python telebot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Работаю с плагином Telebot, в начале нужно выбрать раздел, а затем нажать кнопку старт(вызвать существующую функцию), я не могу вызвать функцию getInfo без аргумента message, поэтому прикрутил сюда второй декоратор, однако это не помогло.

```
@bot.message_handler()
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c:True)
def startMenu(c, message):
  if c.data == 'metal':
    bot.send_message(c.message.chat.id, 'Установлено.')
    url = 'https://directlot.ru/products.php?group=10000&so=3'
    return url
  if c.data == 'tree':
    bot.send_message(c.message.chat.id, 'Установлено.')
    url = 'https://directlot.ru/products.php?group=20000&so=3'
    return url
  if c.data == 'radio':
    bot.send_message(c.message.chat.id, 'Установлено.')
    url = 'https://directlot.ru/products.php?group=30000&so=3'
    return url
  if c.data == 'start':
    global work
    work = True
    bot.send_message(c.message.chat.id, 'Мониторинг запущен.\nЧтобы остановить - напишите /stop')
    getInfo(message)
```

При использовании кнопки с callback.data 'start' получаю следующую ошибку:

> TypeError: startMenu() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c'

Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы вызвать существующую команду или функцию через кнопку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Если ответ помог, поставь галочку слева, новичёк.**

```
import time
bot = telebot.TeleBot("ТОКЕН")   

button_menu = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
button_menu.row('/ping')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def default_test(message):
    if message.text.lower() == "/start":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Выбери действие", reply_markup = button_menu)
        
    if message.text.lower() == "/ping":
       ping(message) 
    
def ping(message):
    nick = message.from_user.username
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"@{nick}")
    
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```